# set all apache sites offline with temporary static cached original pages

Tags: apache-2.2, php, maintenance, seo

I would like to set all virtualhosts on my server down for maintenance for some time.

The temporary page should contain something like

> sorry, the page www.xxx.com is down for maintenance. you can see the
>   cached version here:

**Then the trick:** 
the user should then see the cached page from a cache like googlecache or similar for the requested page as long as the server is down.

This would show the correct content on pages, that are static anyway and give the visitor the needed content in many cases, while I can shut down mysql and other services that would usually be needed to show that pages.

How can I set a global page on all virtualhosts, that parses the original requested URL through PHP?

Comment: why do you want to pollute the internet with SEO keywords?

Comment: not pollute, I just want to show some content

Comment: SEO surely sounds like polluting/vandalism.

Comment: oy, I changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A solution with javascript:**

create a page called

`offline.html`

```
HTTP/1.0 200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>
sorry, the site is currently down for maintenance.<br>
<SCRIPT>
document.write('<iframe src="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'
        +location.href
        +'" style="width:100%;height:95%"></iframe>');
</SCRIPT></body></html>
```

and set up a temporary server with

```
$ apt-get install ucspi-tcp
$ tcpserver 0.0.0.0 80 sh -c 'awk "/^\r*$/ { exit }"; cat offline.html'
```

*but it seems google doesen't allow such a link in an iframe, so another cache will be needed.*

sources:

- [how do i set up a minimal webserver, that serves only one page on all requests?](https://serverfault.com/questions/444747/how-do-i-set-up-a-minimal-webserver-that-serves-only-one-page-on-all-requests)
- [How to modify a URL to get a Google cached version of page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-modify-a-url-to-get-a-google-cached-version-of-page)